# I just want to add a translation patch to the live caption in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, applescript, live, caption

How to get all the text of chrome live caption and always use applescript to translate it into other languages and output it to another window. The following is part of the code that can only print out the text.

Here I am traversing all static controls and getting their values to form a string variable.

```
set endTime to (current date) + 10
repeat
    try
        #log "echo 1"
        tell application "System Events"
            #log "echo 2"
            if exists process "Google Chrome" then
                #log "echo 3"
                tell process "Google Chrome"
                    #log "echo 4"
                    tell window "Live Caption"
                        #log "echo 5"
                        set uiElements to entire contents
                        set uiElem3 to item -3 of uiElements
                        set allTexts to ""
                        
                        repeat with uiElem in uiElements
                            try
                                #log "echo 6"
                                if class of uiElem as string = "static text" then
                                    
                                    #log "echo 7"
                                    set res to value of uiElem as string
                                    if res does not contain "Live Caption is not available at the moment" then
                                        #log "echo 8" #log res
                                        set allTexts to (allTexts & res) & ""
                                        
                                    end if
                                    
                                else
                                    #log "不是static text类型"
                                end if
                            on error errMsg number errNum
                            end try
                        end repeat
                        
                        #log "echo 9"
                        #log (name of uiElem3) & ""
                        #set allTexts to (allTexts & name of uiElem3) & ""
                        #log "echo 10"
                        log allTexts
                        set allTexts to ""
                        log "*************************************************"
                        delay 0.5 
                    end tell
                end tell
            end if
        end tell
        
    on error errMsg number errNum
        if (current date) > endTime then
            exit repeat
        end if
    end try
    
end repeat
```